# Apóstrofo (aspa simples) dentro de aspas em javascript e php

Tags: php, javascript

Queria uma maneira mais elegante de escrever o código abaixo. Ele está passando os parâmetros via GET mas vai com \' e posso até usar uma função do PHP de replace mas queria uma solução sem gambiarra. Repara que fica ' dentro de ' ai coloco o \' mas ele vai no parâmetro e se coloco \" do php não funciona. Segue o código

```
onClick=\"window.parent.document.getElementById('webcam_show').src='webcam_html5/index.php?text_area=\'ta_proprietario_altera_foto64\'&frame_destino=\'frame_proprietario_foto_altera\'';window.parent.div_mostra('webcam')\"
```

Comment: Não existe nada de gambiarra em escapar uma string

Comment: Blza, até concordo que não seria o fim do mundo, mas estou muito chato com este projeto, queria saber se tem uma maneira de não fazer isso. obrigado.

Comment: Tem como postar mais do seu código, desde a variável que recebe a string que você quer escapar?
Do jeito que esta, confesso que para mim, esta um pouco difícil de entender

Comment: mas pq esse \' na linha? Se é no php não é necessário. O valor da variavel não necessita de aspas. Mas se contudo, todavia, mesmo assim quiser colocar aspas simples substitua \' por ".chr(39)."  Veja como fica:  ..... index.php?text_area=".chr(39)."ta_proprietario_altera_foto64".chr(39)."&frame_destino ..... Mas o melhor mesmo é atender a solicitação do MarceloBoni para que possamos responder com certeza.

Comment: o \' na linha aparece pois não posso passar uma parametro texto via get sem aspas. Obrigado pela ajuda, parece uma boa solução.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade seria mover o código para uma função.

Desse modo seu HTML poderia ficar assim:

```
onClick="myOnClick()"
```

e no JavaScript:

```
function myOnClick(e) {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('webcam_show').src="webcam_html5/index.php?text_area='ta_proprietario_altera_foto64'&frame_destino='frame_proprietario_foto_altera'";
    window.parent.div_mostra('webcam');
}
```

Comment: Verdade, muito obrigado, bem mais elegante.